# Numerical Analysis.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The problem says:

> - Apply Euler's method with $h=1/4$ to the I.V.P
>     \begin{align}
>   y'_1&=-y_1-y_2,\\
>   y'_2&=y_1-y_2\end{align}
>     in $[0,1]$ with $y_1(0)=1$, $y_2(0)=0$
> - Verify that $y_1(t)=e^{-t} \cos(t)$ and $y_2(t)=e^{-t}\sin(t)$ is the exact solution.
> - Find the Global Truncations errors of $y_1$ and $y_2$ in $t=1$

For Euler's method I computed:
\begin{align}
w_{0,1}&=1& &\to& w_{j+1,1}&=1+1/4(-1-0)=3/4\\
w_{0,2}&=0& &\to& w_{j+1,2}&=0+1/4(1-0)=1/4
\end{align}
To check that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions is trivial.

The problem I'm stuck with is to find the Global T. Errors, so if if you can help me with that I'd be grateful.

Also if you noticed any mistake in my procedure, please let me know.

Comment: There is context missing. What is the global truncation error. Are you to find or approximate a constant $C$ so that the global error is approximately $Ch$ or just the difference of your approximation to the exact solution?

Comment: Please add the additional steps, at the moment you only have the step for $j=0$, you need also to compute the steps $j=1,2,3$.

Comment: Sorry, Sauer Numerical Analysis defines the Global Truncation Error: $g_i=|w_i-y_i|$ and Local Truncation Error or one-step error: $e_{i+1}=|w_{i+1}-z(t_{i+1})|$

Answer (score 1):

Just compute the values, to have something to compare to, compute also values for smaller step sizes.

```
from math import exp, cos, sin

def y1sol(t): return exp(-t)*cos(t)
def y2sol(t): return exp(-t)*sin(t)

def Euler(N):
    ''' print values at k/4 with N Euler steps in between '''
    h = 0.25/N
    t, y1, y2 = 0.0, 1.0, 0.0
    result = "N=%4d: "%N
    for k in range(4):
        for j in range(N):
            y1, y2 = y1 + h*(-y1-y2), y2+h*(y1-y2)
        t += 0.25
        result += "y(%4.2f) = (%10.7f, %10.7f), err = (%8.3e, %8.3e);  "%(t, y1, y2, y1-y1sol(t), y2-y2sol(t))
    print result

for N in [1,10,100]: Euler(N)
```

with results

```
N=   1: y(0.25) = ( 0.7500000,  0.2500000), err = (-4.590e-03, 5.732e-02);  y(0.50) = ( 0.5000000,  0.3750000), err = (-3.228e-02, 8.421e-02);  y(0.75) = ( 0.2812500,  0.4062500), err = (-6.438e-02, 8.427e-02);  y(1.00) = ( 0.1093750,  0.3750000), err = (-8.939e-02, 6.544e-02);  
N=  10: y(0.25) = ( 0.7534317,  0.1974906), err = (-1.158e-03, 4.812e-03);  y(0.50) = ( 0.5286568,  0.2975913), err = (-3.624e-03, 6.805e-03);  y(0.75) = ( 0.3395353,  0.3286195), err = (-6.090e-03, 6.636e-03);  y(1.00) = ( 0.1909175,  0.3146473), err = (-7.849e-03, 5.087e-03);  
N= 100: y(0.25) = ( 0.7544698,  0.1931510), err = (-1.200e-04, 4.726e-04);  y(0.50) = ( 0.5319173,  0.2914531), err = (-3.634e-04, 6.668e-04);  y(0.75) = ( 0.3450211,  0.3226329), err = (-6.043e-04, 6.496e-04);  y(1.00) = ( 0.1979911,  0.3100579), err = (-7.750e-04, 4.981e-04);
```

The error progression very neatly demonstrates the convergence/global error order 1.